# How do adapters work with different number of pin inputs/outputs?

Tags: adapter

I'm going to be working on something that requires me to use a GPIB to USB adapter, which made me look up the pin diagram for both. The GPIB has 24 pins, whereas a USB only has 4. The USB has a ground, VCC, Data+, and Data-. Are the extra pins from the GPIB encoded onto the Data pins somehow? I'm looking for a general answer as I'm just curious, I don't need the specifics for a USB-GPIB adapter (unless each converter has specific methods.)

Comment: You *really* don't want someone to go into a full treatment of the USB spec...

Comment: USB can also connect a keyboard which has 100+ keys so 24 pins is nothing! Seriously, USB is a general-purpose data bus that can act as a transport for almost any kind of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPIB (General Purpose Interface Bus) was originally developed by Hewlett-Packard in the late 1960's as the HP-IB (Hewlett-Packard Interface Bus) to connect various HP lab instruments together, such as digital multimeters, programmable power supplies, function generators, and logic analyzers.  It first became a de facto standard, but by 1975, it was formalized as IEEE-488.

GPIB is a parallel interface, meaning each of the eight bits of a data byte are sent at the same time.  So this requires 16 wires -- eight for the signal wires and eight more for a ground for each signal.  The remaining eight out of the 24 total are used for handshaking and bus management.

If you wanted to connect a CPC to a GPIB network, you could buy a card and install it inside the PC.

Parallel interfaces, such as GPIB and [Centronix interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284) (for printers) are seldom used anymore because of the higher cost of the cables and connectors compared to serial interfaces like USB.  There used to be Centronix printer ports on all PC's, now the Centronix interface between computers and printers has been replaced by USB or WiFi.

USB has four wires: power, ground, and data+, data-.  Both data lines carry the same information, but with opposite polarities (this is called differential signaling and is done to insure a cleaner signal.)  So USB cables can only send one bit at a time, in only one direction at a time.  But they run very fast compared with these older parallel interfaces.

This [USB to GPIB controller](http://prologix.biz/downloads/PrologixGpibUsbManual-6.0.pdf), includes its own set of commands which allows the GPIB interface to be controlled by a serial interface program like RealTerm (or a program sending commands and data over a virtual serial interface).

The data goes out of the USB interface in serial (D+, D- pins), and inside the GPIB controller box the bits are assembled back into bytes and sent to the instrument in parallel (or read back from an instrument).  The controller box handles all of the handshake details locally necessary to satisfy the GPIB bus timing.

Comment: I'd think that something like that would use CDC instead of having to invent a new protocol. I suppose it may not support all the handshaking though...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Actually it turns out the box I referenced uses an FTDI UART chip -- so it actually presents the GPIB interface as a virtual COM port.  And yes they did invent a whole set of proprietary commands to run the interface (see manual referenced in my answer for details).